# Javascript functions using memory on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory

I have a project in one page. And Im using websocket for communication. Sometimes my page working a few days. Im triying to call empty function and chrome memory always increasing. Its normal on firefox, opera, edge... its only increasing on chrome. What can I do for this issue?

And I want to add this,

```
var intervals = [];
function testData(len) {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        intervals.push(
            setInterval(function () { }, 1))
    }
    return "Started test (" + (len * 1000) + " times in a sec.)"
}
function stopTest() {
    for (var i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) 
        clearInterval(intervals[i]);
    return "Stopped";
}
```

this is my test function. This function is empty but still increasing memory when I run this.

```
testData(1000000);
```

And when I stop this, memory is waiting, not decreasing.
I hope I told well. Thanks for reading.

Comment: But your setting 1,000,000 intervals, obviously this is going to use memory. It's really not clear what your problem is here or what your asking?

Comment: Im asking why its not clear memory? Firefox and the others always clear

Comment: Use chrome's built-in profiling tools to find out yourself. My guess is that for some reason, Chrome is keeping references to those anonymous functions and not collecting them

Comment: @Liam, he is saying that in Firefox, the memory is released once the function stops, but in chrome, the memory stays in use and keeps increasing every time he calls this function.

Comment: Yes I was triying to say that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated chrome to v58.0.3029.81 then its normal now. Thanks for comments.